# Using array to login in for loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, invoke-command

I am trying to set ip on multiple term.servers in our domain.

I am pretty new to powershell, and have tried to search arround to find the right answer witouh luck.

My code looks like this:

```
$adcomputere = (Get-ADComputer -filter * | Where-Object name -like term*srv).Name

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $adcomputere.count -1; $i++) `
{   
    $cred = New-object system.management.automation.PSCredential ("$adcomputere[$i]\administrator",(ConvertTo-SecureString 'P@ssword' -AsPlainText -Force))

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $adcomputere[$i] -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock `
    {
      Set-Printer -Name Mommark-vaegt2 -PortName 192.168.48.43
    } & $adcomputere
}
```

My problem is the use of $adcomputere[$i]. i get this error:

```
ParserError: 
Line |
   1 |  …  Invoke-Command -ComputerName ${using:adcomputere}[${using:i}] -Crede …
     |                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~
     | Expression is not allowed in a Using expression.
```

Can anyone help me on the right course?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR5v4.png)

Comment: The error doesn't match your script...

Comment: Just added a picture to show the error.

Comment: Did you try it directly in powershell instead of the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you tried it yourself and there are some smart ideas, but the loop can be done much easier:

Your FOR loop is prone to human errors. Two of them can be seen in your script. First is the enumeration. You count from 0 to 1 less than (`-lt`) the number of results you have -1 (`$adcomputere.count -1`). That's a total of 2 less. For a count of 3 you count to the number less than 3-1, that's 0 and 1.
The other mistake is when you try to use the object at this position in the string `"$adcomputere[$i]\administrator"`. The string will evaluate the 2 variables and take `[` and `]` as part of the string. This will be all the names of the computers in one line + `[$i]`. One way would be to use `"${$adcomputere[$i]}\administrator"` to evaluate the part in `${}` first and use that in the string. However, there is an easier alternative.

Use FOREACH: You can use `FOREACH` just with the collection of objects so that the used object in each loop is `$_` (`$adcomputere | foreach {}`) or name the variable yourself for enhanced readability `foreach ($computer in $adcomputere){}`. Let's go with the second one for now:

```
foreach ($Computer in $adcomputere ) # No need for "`". FOR, IF, FOREACH and the others expect {} after () anyway
{
    $cred = New-object system.management.automation.PSCredential ("$Computer\administrator",(ConvertTo-SecureString 'P@ssword' -AsPlainText -Force))

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock `
        {
            Set-Printer -Name Mommark-vaegt2 -PortName 192.168.48.43
        } #& $adcomputere       < you don't need that. That would execute $adcomputere if it was a scriptblock and causes an error at this position
}
```

The next question is, is the local admin even able to connect remotely? Try to connect to one of the computers with `Enter-PSSession`:

```
$Computer = $adcomputere[0]
$cred = New-object system.management.automation.PSCredential ("$Computer\administrator",(ConvertTo-SecureString 'P@ssword' -AsPlainText -Force))
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $cred
# exit with Exit-PSSession or just exit
```